# Insert to database using @Async in Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm writing a web application which offers image files upload.

After the file's uploaded (using JavaScript) the user needs to submit a form.
After submitting, image files are processed (making thumbnails and so on ), that's why I wanted to pass the HttpServletRequest to an @Async service.

Unfortunately when I use @Async my application doesn't insert anything in the database. There is no error also. It's just not happening.

When I remove @Async, it works fine, but the form submission takes a long time.

I also use @EnableAsync after @Service.

What is wrong ?

```
@ResponseBody
public String addAdvertisement(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

    addAdvertisementService.addAdvertisement(request);

    return "OK";
}
```

AND ASYNC SERVICE

```
@Service
@EnableAsync
public class AddAdvertisementService {
    public String addAdvertisement(HttpServletRequest request){

       ...

       System.out.println(" REQUEST " );

int customerId = customerNotRegisteredService.addCustomer("", ipAddress, email, phoneNumber);
```

REQUEST is displayed on the console, but "addCustomer" is not invoked...

Comment: I suspect the issue is that because you're handing your DB code over to a new thread, there isn't a transaction, an exception is getting thrown and because there's no global exception handler configured for that thread, it's  dying silently. Try wrapping your DB code in a `try{}catch(Exception e){}` and either log it or print it to the `stdout`. You also aren't going to be able to return an `int` from that method without wrapping it in a `Future`. If you could it would be no different than the synchronous approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to scoped nature of request object.

With @Async you are processing it in a different thread. So servlet thread is free and your request is complete.

To do is properly either clone your request and pass cloned object or you can use Future object and block main thread.

Cloning HTTP request and response is possible via HttpServletResponseWrapper class http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html.

Comment: Ok, you were right - the problem was with sending HttpServletRequest. When i've sent only parameters, it works fine. Thanks